# Read text file row after a certain string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-3.5

I am reading a text file using **C# (.NET 3.5)**. loading file reading it line by line everything is fine working good but I want to read it from the center of a row. The Data present in .txt file is in following format:

```
12-09-2015 00:05:98 140.25.1.37 00120915000598  7421 03456***89 13 94569

13-09-2015 00:08:90 140.25.1.37 00130915000890     7421 034564***654 94569

13-09-2015 00:12:85 140.25.1.37 00130915001285 7421 0345***95114   94569

14-09-2015 00:11:20 140.25.1.37 00140915001120   7421 0345****9814 94569

16-09-2015 01:20:73 140.25.1.37 00160915012073     7421 03456***7698 94569
```

**I need Data after IP 140.25.1.37**..

there are more then **21000 entries** in each file and data center generates like 100's of file. Please suggest me anything that is fast and efficient too.

Thank you

Comment: If it's always in the same format why don't you just write a method to find the index of the second space in the line then substring the line starting at the index

Comment: per each line with the ipaddress... or the entire contents after each time you see the ip address?

Comment: Why not just `Split` using the space character as a delimiter?

Comment: matthew Whited 
Hi, Per each line after IP.. because each line having same IP after date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file into a string and using the LastIndex method:

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(filepath);  
int i = readText.LastIndexOf("140.25.1.37");
```

You now have the index of the last occurring ip address, and you can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your looking for the data after that specified IP for each line, use the index of the end of the IP to grab the remaining substring.

```
string IP = "140.25.1.37 ";
string DataAfterIP = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(IP) + IP.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is fun...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scanPath = @"c:\your\path";
            var scanPattern = "*.log";
            var outfile = "result.log";

            var logs = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(scanPath, scanPattern)
                       from line in file.AsLines()
                       where line.Substring(20, 11) == "140.25.1.37"
                       select line;
            logs.WriteAsLinesTo(outfile);
        }
    }

    public static class Tools
    {
        public static void WriteAsLinesTo(this IEnumerable<string> lines, string filename)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
                foreach (var line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> AsLines(this string filename)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    yield return reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want the data for each line after the ip address change `select line;` to `select line.Substring(31);`

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, This is the first time I asked from StackOverflow. Thank you for your quick answers.
Stay Blessed